# Function with union argument indirectly causes inexplicable errors on union members

Tags: flowtype

In the following block of code, flow errors occur on the `OuterY` and `OuterZ` type definitions *only* when the `getInnerValues` function is present.

The errors complain that `"Y"` and `"Z"` are incompatible with `"X"`. For example: *"string literal `Y` is incompatible with string literal `X`."*.

```
/* @flow */

type Inner<T> = { value: T };

type OuterX = { inner: Array<Inner<"X">> };
type OuterY = { inner: Array<Inner<"Y">> };
type OuterZ = { inner: Array<Inner<"Z">> };

type Outer = OuterX | OuterY | OuterZ;

// If the next line is present, errors occur on
// lines 6 and 7 complaining that "Y" and "Z" are
// incompatible with "X". When the next line is
// commented out, the errors go away. Why??
const getInnerValues = (outer: Outer) => outer.inner.map(inner => inner.value);
```

Why is this happening?

[Click here to see the issue on **flow.org/try**](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCSAdsXgE4A8AKgHxgC8YA3mAG4CGMArngFxhqYAL4BudNnxgA8twwUAGoxZgAlqQoCAguXIcslEmSoAiBSdr0xmXAVnzyATWWt1x7bv2GNpxxaviknZyFABaLmo+HnoGRhSUJqH+IuI2UvYUyhnkSgA+MiFOYPnZoanAwERQYBgAFgRkAB4YYDDqBKoAzmA45HideMQYADRgFORw5N1wAMYz3ORgcMSoFa3t3QBsYBzEACZgAOxgM3AAtjgwHOrqAOY1tRwtJn47+2CJJjt9q5XqpxcnqoAEYwAgIVR1D7mAB0YAA6vViA8GnhmusyGpOr8TuczoN5Ac4HJRnUCONJt1bnAdgh9HDEVgAPxM1CnYidFq3PAYOLkABqXF43SYAApiQ4BNkAJSMegSigwtyKs4cHCi5WLBj0TUwzg8PDS8RAA)

[Click here to see the same issue with stricter typing on **flow.org/try**](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCSAdsXgE4A8A1ACoB8YAvGAN4A+Y1AbgIYwBXPAC4wtMOwC+AbnTZ8YAPICMFABrM2nagEtSFUQBIASnl4ATRcRhYAguXK8slEmSoAiNe-qMps+QTKquQAmpocXHpuRqYWVjb2js6uFJTuId6+Mpi4gSoUAFrh2lEGYCZmltZ2Dk4u+h4FmRLZOQpBFJod5Bqc3WF9+eQFsqjAwERQYBgAFgRkAB4YYDB6BDoAzmA45HgbeMQYADRgFORw5FtwAMbXAuRgcMRjE6tkWwBsYLzE5mAA7GBrnAALY4GC8PR6ADm0xmvGW6Xc31+YHcTW+uxeYD0wLBCJ0ACMYAQEDpZmivAA6MAAdTmxDh8zwSxWaxxG2xeJBB1UfzgKhOswIZwuW2hcG+CCcNPpWAA-PLUMDiBtltC8BgUuQAGr8IRbFgACgFwVE3QAlMxGKaKFTSuQqSDeDgjQ7rTiGlS+II8BbZEA)

Comment: Nice try with the second example. A lot of people could answer their own questions if they tried making everything covariant with read-only arrays. It doesn't apply here, but it's a very useful way to debug flow errors.

Answer (score 0):

Flow doesn't realize that there exists an `inner` property of type `{value: string}` for all the possible cases of `Outer`. One way to fix this is to type the function to accept an object with the expected type:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCSAdsXgE4A8AKgHxgC8YA3mAG4CGMArngFxhqYAL4BudNnxgA8twwUAGoxZgAlqQoCAguXIcslEmSoAiBSdr0xmXAVnzyATWWt1x7bv2GNpxxaviknZyFABaLmo+HnoGRhSUJqH+IuI2UvYUyhnkSgA+MiFOYPnZoanAwGDEcGAU5HDkAM6oAMZwxI0YYADmeBhx5ABqXLyNygAUcIUCzG6aYDoxlMycPPxgneTq3cK0wgCUjLSoAJBTDgB0c+QXALYcOOPXR5HGF6u8++JAA))

```
/* @flow */

type Inner<T> = { value: T };

type OuterX = { inner: Array<Inner<"X">> };
type OuterY = { inner: Array<Inner<"Y">> };
type OuterZ = { inner: Array<Inner<"Z">> };

type Outer = OuterX | OuterY | OuterZ;

// no errors
const getInnerValues = (outer: {inner: Array<{value: string}>}) =>
    outer.inner.map(inner => inner.value);
```

Another way to do this (probably the better way) is to redefine `Outer` as type which accepts a type parameter. Then you can generically type your `getInnerValues` function to accept generic `Outer` instances:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCSAdsXgE4A8AKgHxgC8YA3mAG4CGMArngFxhqYAL4BudNnxgA8twwUAGoxZgAlqQoCAguXIcslEmSoAiBSdr0xmXAVnzyATWWt1x7bv2GNpxxaviknZyFABaLmo+HnoGRhSUJqH+IuI2UvbxdC6oYJHuYDox3sY0lrnlFZVgqMLowMBgxHBgFORw5ADOqADGcMQdGGAA5ngYceQAaly8HcqlABRwIeQCGVR0AJSM9EsOAHRuFHsAthw484fk23lHnDx4G+JAA))

```
/* @flow */

type Inner<T> = { value: T };

type OuterX = { inner: Array<Inner<"X">> };
type OuterY = { inner: Array<Inner<"Y">> };
type OuterZ = { inner: Array<Inner<"Z">> };

type Outer<T> = {
  inner: Array<Inner<T>>               
}

// no errors
const getInnerValues = <T>(outer: Outer<T>) => outer.inner.map(inner => inner.value);
```